# Circular pipe situation

Tags: pipe, read, write

More of an academic/theory question - say I have process A piping into process B:

```
A | B
```

normally, the way pipes are designed, is if process A dies, the pipeline will gracefully shutdown. However, if process B dies, there will be a write error if A tries to keep writing to B.

Is there an acceptable way for B to die first, is it possible to make it circular in some fashion?

This probably won't work, but something like this:

```
mkfifo circ
A < circ | B > circ
```

the question, again, is if there is a graceful way for B to die before A?

Comment: I suppose "circ" could be used in more than one way - if there is no OS supported way, at the very least B could write "die" to circ and then A could read it and then die first on B's behalf?

Comment: If B exits first, A doesn't just get an error, but by default also gets the SIGPIPE signal, making it exit. And usually shells etc. just ignore that particular error exit, even if they'd print diagnostics for other cases where a child process exits due to a signal. Something like `produce lots of output | grep -q keyword` would be a common case to cause just that. Or `cat /dev/zero | head -c 1234`. Graceful or not, it works in practice.

Comment: "graceful" is a human terminology, and doesn't really matter to software :) What matters is that both mechanisms are well-defined and lead to deterministic behaviour (at least in the use cases sketched here).

Comment: well more objectively, graceful as in less extraneous logs, less extraneous signals/messages, etc

Comment: The graceful way for `A` to handle the death of `B` would be to catch the `PIPE` signal that it gets when trying to write to the closed pipe, and do whatever it needs to do to deal with the fact that it can't no longer write to the pipe. I'm confused about what role the FIFO plays here, so I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: @kuz if the SIGPIPE wasn't sent to A by default, then the fifo would be used to send a similar message, but I guess that SIGPIPE will do the trick